# How can I pass an array to a C++ function on GraalWasm with the polyglot API?

Tags: java, c++, graalvm

I've written a simple test C++ file. The C++ file contains a simple function that sets the value of the pointer to `42`.

```cpp
extern "C" {
    void foo(uint8_t* bytes) {
        bytes[0] = 42;
    }
}
```

Then I used Emscripten to compile the C++ file to wasm.

```
emcc foo.cpp -o foo.wasm -s EXPORT_ALL=1
```

I tried the following code to call the function, but it seems that the `uint8_t*` parameter is converted to `Integer` and passing `byte[]` to it is not allowed. I guess it stands for a pointer to the WASM internal memory, but I don't know how to allocate a buffer, copy the java array to it, and copy the content back after the function call.

```java
static final Context CONTEXT = Context.newBuilder("wasm")
    .allowAllAccess(true).option("wasm.Builtins", "wasi_snapshot_preview1,env:emscripten").build();

var bin = IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("/foo.wasm");
CONTEXT.eval(Source.newBuilder("wasm", ByteSequence.create(bin), "foo").build());
var foo = CONTEXT.getBindings("wasm").getMember("main").getMember("foo");
byte[] arr = {0};
System.out.println(arr[0]);  // 0
foo.execute(...);  // TODO how to achieve this?
System.out.println(arr[0]);  // 42
```

I want my program to be cross-platform, so I don't want to use LLVM on GraalVM (it's said that LLVM bitcode is platform-dependent). Do anyone have idea on how to achieve this? It's OK to copy the java array to the WASM memory, but passing the array directly will be better.

Comment: Does `emcc` understand if you make it `std::vector<uint8_t> bytes` instead of `uint8_t* bytes` ?